# Indexing failed with solr in grails 1.3.7

Tags: tomcat, grails, solr

I'm currently working on a grails project whith solr plugin.

**grails version** : 1.3.7

**grails start-solr** output :

```
/path/.grails/1.3.7/projects/projectName/plugins/solr-0.2/scripts/StartSolr.
Starting Solr - Solr HOME is
/path/.grails/1.3.7/projects/projectName/solr-home
Console access: http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

I'v edited data-config.xml file as needed :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoreconnect=true" user="user"
        password="password" />
/*...*/
```

I also edit DataSource file :

```
/*...*/
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
//            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
//            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB"
            dbCreate = "update"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
/*...*/
```

I'v reloaded solr configuration going to this url:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=reload-config
```

Then, when i'm visiting this url :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

I receive this message :

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">11</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="initArgs">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
        <str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:8.711</str>
        <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
        <str name="Total Rows Fetched">0</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
        <str name="Full Dump Started">2012-09-20 14:53:56</str>
        <str name="">Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.</str>
        <str name="Rolledback">2012-09-20 14:53:56</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

Do I forget something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly found the answer :

After opening solr log file located here :

> tail -f
>   ~/.grails/1.3.7/projects/PROJECT-NAME/solr-home/logs/AAAA_MM_JJ.stderrout.log

I see the following error :

> GRAVE: Full Import failed
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could
>   not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1

So i download the jdbc driver on mysql website :

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=13597

I move the **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar** file of the package here :

> mv mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
>   ~/.grails/1.3.7/projects/PROJECT-NAME/solr-home/lib/

Hope it will be usefull for someone !